# Dataprep job keeps failing when unioning

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I have two datasets that I'm trying to Union using dataprep. Both have 300+ columns and require a combination of matching by name and manually adding columns to match since the names aren't always the same.

After matching the columns and saving, the job fails everytime at the 5 minute mark. After it fails and I try to go back into the recipe to check the matched columns, the columns that I matched are no longer matched.

Any solutions or additional steps to fix this would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update the question with the data flow logs? this will show in more detail what is causing the failure. there is no timeout limit on data flow that should in itself cause this problem

Comment: It actually doesn't start a dataflow job and unable to view logs. I've run parts of the dataprep flow before the actual union and those jobs are successful and I am able to view the dataflow logs for those.

Comment: what is running for 5 minutes if the data flow job doesn't start

Comment: Unsure, it just spins in Dataprep and then fails at the 5 min mark.

Comment: Anything in GCP logging under Dataflow Step?

Comment: I checked the dataflow jobs here: https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow and there are no failed jobs for the union there

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?resource=dataflow_step

Comment: Yep, started the dataprep job again that failed while streaming the logs. No new entries came in.

Comment: wierd. try posting about it here: https://community.trifacta.com/s/topic/0TO16000000g8CSGAY/google-cloud-dataprep

Comment: Will do, thank you for the help!